# Sass: Generate a root class in nested using `class.&`

Tags: css, sass

I don't understand why the code below generates `.test a.test {color: black;}`
instead expected `a.test {color: black;}`?
I thought it's an opposite method to `&.a` which generates just `test.a` (in this case).

```
.test {
  width: 10px;
  a#{&} {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to style `a.test` with class `a` nested in `.test`.
There is a special sass directive `@at-root` which allows to emit a style block at root of the list.

```
// Sass
.test {
  @at-root a#{&} {color: blue;}
}

// Generated CSS
a.test {color: blue;}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/rafal_r3/pen/LRpzYq)